# Download upload file from specific folder

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, file-upload, entity-framework-4

I want to download upload file which is inside a folder into my project.. 
My Database Table
[image]

My Upload Code is

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadPatDoc.FileName);
string pathName = Path.GetFullPath(FileUploadPatDoc.PostedFile.FileName);
FileUploadPatDoc.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/PatientDocuments/") +filename);
fsDocuments.FileName = filename; // fsDocument is Table Object name
fsDocuments.FilePath = pathName;
```

It works nicely and Store documents in "PatientDocuments" folder which is inside my project. 
Now when I want to download it from Gridview using Image-button that times it couldn't find it's destination **Path**. 
Here is the Upload code

```
 ImageButton Btn = (ImageButton)sender;
 GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)Btn.NamingContainer;
 string fileName, filePath;
 Label file = (Label)grdPatientDocument.Rows[row.RowIndex].FindControl("lblFileName");
 Label path = (Label)grdPatientDocument.Rows[row.RowIndex].FindControl("lblFilePath");

        if (file != null)
        {
            fileName = file.Text;
            filePath = path.Text;
            Response.ContentType = filePath;
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
            Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(fileName));
            Response.End();   
        }
```

It generate following error

> "Could not find file E:\CoreZ
>   IT\June\Hospital\22-06\Final\CZ_BHC\CZ_BHC\BHC\CV_MD.Golam_Shahriar.pdf'"

But I need to find this file from `E:....\PatientDocuments\CV_MD.Golam_Shahriar.pdf`

Please help me and I am using VS 2012... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName + "");
Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
Response.End();
```

Comment: After implement your given code it gives me following error 
'Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\CV_MD.Golam_Shahriar.pdf'.'

Comment: replace Response.TransmitFile(filePath); to Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/PatientDocuments/") +filename);